# pl/python para aurora aws

Tags: postgresql, aws

alguien sabe si Aurora de aws tiene soporte para pl/python como lo tiene postgresql desde su version 11, estamos migrando la DB a RDS de aws y los procedimientos están hechos con pl/python actualmente.

Saludos!!!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: creo que está clara la pregunta, es saber si Aurora tiene o no soporte para poder desarrollar procedimientos con pl/python.

Comment: @ManuelBarrionuevo quien te ha comentado es un bot ... no se lo tengas en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

Pl/python es una extensión en PostgreSQL, por ende recomiendo buscar en la documentación de RDS para aurora con PostgreSQL y ver que dice de las extensiones que soporta, pero según veo en [este enlace](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraPostgreSQLReleaseNotes/AuroraPostgreSQL.Extensions.html) no tiene soporte para pl/python, y si para otros lenguajes no "confiables" como: plperl, plv8, pltcl

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!!!